# I keep getting false and not true in this javascript anagram problem

Tags: javascript, anagram

Hi Im using Javascript to work on an anagram problem. I am having issues comparing the 2 objects I have made out of the 2 strings that were put into the function.

The function should return true if the 2 strings have the same letters occurring the same number of times. Regardless of order in the string. You ignore the casing of the letters too, to do that I made all strings lowercase. Here is my code:

```
//example:
        //validAnagram('', '') //true
        //validAnagram('aaz', 'zza') //false
        
        const validAnagram = (str1, str2) => {
            str1 = str1.toLowerCase()
            str2 = str2.toLowerCase()
            const frequency1 = {}
            const frequency2 = {}

            //if lengths of string isnt the same automatically make it false

            if(str1.length !== str2.length){
                return false
            }

            //putting letters of the strings with their frequencies in the objects
            for(let letter of str1){
                if(!frequency1[letter]){
                    frequency1[letter] = 1
                } 
                else {
                    frequency1[letter]++
                }
            }

            for(let letter of str2){
                if(!frequency2[letter]){
                    frequency2[letter] = 1
                } 
                else {
                    frequency2[letter]++
                }
            }

            for(let char in frequency1){
                if(!(frequency2[char])){
                    return false
                } 
                else if(frequency2[char] !== frequency1[char]){
                    console.log(char)
                    return false
                }
                else{
                    return true
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: You should not be returning true inside the loop. Why is `frequency2` commented out?

Comment: You need the `return true` in the last `for` loop to be **outside** the loop. You have to make sure that the loop conditions are true for **all** of the characters.

Comment: This is a prime case for using a debugger, or learning how to use a debugger, if you don't know yet.

Comment: `const validAnagram = (str1, str2) => 
  str1.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('') === str2.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('');`

Comment: Why do you expect `aaz` and `zza` to be anagrams in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** I searched all unique characters from 2 string and saved then in array

**Second:** I concat 2 arrays and then using set, removed all duplicate items (characters)

**Third:** I loop through each character and find the occurrence of that item
forth: if occurrence matched or not, or if the character actually not exists in any of the string, can be found in the console.

```js
const string1 = 'dafdsef dgrg tdyhjTdh drdd@ dgrgrth-grth'
        const string2 = '@dafdsef dgrg tdyhjtdh drdd dgrgr;thgrth'
        console.log("strings matched : "+test_string(string1 , string2));

        function test_string(string1 , string2){
            jointArray = [...unique_char(string1.toLowerCase()), ...unique_char(string2.toLowerCase())]
            neewarray = [...new Set([...jointArray])]
            ok = true;
            neewarray.forEach( v=> {
                var re = new RegExp(v, 'g');
                if(string1.match(re) && string2.match(re) ){
                    if( string1.match(re).length == string2.match(re).length ) {
                        console.log(` ${v} => matched in 2 strings`)
                    }
                    else{
                        ok = false;
                        console.log(` ${v} => not matched in 2 strings`)
                    }
                }
                else if(string1.match(re)){
                    ok = false;
                    console.log(` ${v} => not avialable in a string1 `) 
                }
                else if(string2.match(re)){
                    ok = false;
                    console.log(` ${v} => not avialable in a string2 `) 
                }
            
            })
            return ok;
        }
        

        function unique_char(str1){
            var str=str1;
            var uniq_array=[];
            for (var x=0;x < str.length;x++){
                if(uniq_array.indexOf(str.charAt(x))==-1){
                    uniq_array.push(str[x]);  
                }
            }
            return uniq_array;  
        }
```